# how to change the statusbar after didenterbackgroud?

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications, statusbar

I saw a application 'Sleep Cycle' that changes the status bar color to red and displayed continuously even the application is in the background by pressing home button.
I know how to display notification but it wont display continuously and changing the color.Any one knows about this? PLease help.

Answer (score 0):

They are 3 special status bar colors :

- Blue when sharing connection
- Green when a call is active
- Red when an application is using special phone features in background (like the microphone)

In iOS7 you can change the status bar in your application by either

- Setting the tintColor of the navigationBar if you have one navigationController
- Or set a rectangle view with frame {0,0,screenWidth,20}